# How to partition a single batch into many invocations to save memory

Tags: tensorflow

I have a somewhat big model, that can only be trained on GPU with a small batch size, but I need to use a larger batch size (from other experiments, I know this improves final accuracy and convergence time)

Caffe provides a nice solution to this problem through the 'iter_size' option, which splits a batch into n smaller batches, accumulate n gradients then update once

how can this be implemented efficiently in TensorFlow ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use smaller batches, compute the gradients manually, and then add them up and apply them at once. For example, if you want a batch size of 100, compute gradients for 10 batches of 10, then add the gradients and apply them. This is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#processing-gradients-before-applying-them).

You can use the tf.gradients() op to compute the gradients for each batch separately and add them. Then use the apply_gradients() method on whatever optimizer you want to perform the training step.

Comment: Code ? as this is actually much more involved than it seems