# How to feed the list of gradients, or (grad, variable name) pairs, to my model

Tags: tensorflow

This is related to a previous question: [How to partition a single batch into many invocations to save memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976761/how-to-partition-a-single-batch-into-many-invocations-to-save-memory), and also to [How to train a big model with relatively large batch size on a single GPU using Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341549/how-to-train-a-big-model-with-relatively-large-batch-size-on-a-single-gpu-using); but, still I couldn't find the exact answer. For example, the answer to another related question  [tensorflow - run optimizer op on a large batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555276/tensorflow-run-optimizer-op-on-a-large-batch) doesn't work for me (btw. it wasn't accepted and there are no more comments there).

I want to try to simulate larger batch size but using only one GPU.
So, I need to compute the gradients for every smaller batch, aggregate/average them across several such smaller batches, and only then apply.

(Basically, it's like synchronized distributed SGD, but on a single device/GPU, performed serially. Of course, the acceleration advantage of distributed SGD is lost but larger batch size itself will maybe enable convergence to larger accuracy and larger step size, as indicated by a few recent papers.)

To keep memory requirement low, I should do standard SGD with small batches, update the gradients after every iteration and then call `optimizer.apply_gradients()` (where `optimizer` is one of the implemented optimizers).

So, everything looks simple but when I go to implement it, it is actually not so trivial.

For example, I would like to use one `Graph`, compute gradients for each iteration, and then, when multiple batches are processed, sum the gradients and pass them to my model. But the list itself can't be fed into the `feed_dict` parameter of `sess.run`. Also, passing gradients directly doesn't exactly work, I get the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` (I think the reason is that I can't pass in the `numpy.ndarray`, only tensorflow variable).
I could define a placeholder for the gradients, but for that I would need tu build the model first (to specify the trainable variables etc.).

All in all, please tell me there is a simpler way to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simpler way than what you have already been told. That way may seem complicated at first, but it actually is really simple. You just have to use the low level API to manually calculate the gradients for each batch, average over them and than manually feed the averaged gradients to the optimizer to apply them.

I'll try to provide some stripped down code of how to do this. I'll use dots as placeholders for actual code which would depend on the problem. What you would usually do would be something like this:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
[...]
input = tf.placeholder(...)
[...]
loss = ...
[...]
# initialize the optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
# define operation to apply the gradients
minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss)
[...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = tf.Session(config=CONFIG)
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(1, MAX_STEPS + 1):
        data = ...
        loss = session.run([minimize, loss],
                           feed_dict={input: data})[1]
```

What you want to do instead now, to average over multiple batches to preserver memory would be this:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
[...]
input = tf.placeholder(...)
[...]
loss = ...
[...]
# initialize the optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)

# grab all trainable variables
trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()

# define variables to save the gradients in each batch
accumulated_gradients = [tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(tv.initialized_value()),
                                     trainable=False) for tv in
                         trainable_variables]

# define operation to reset the accumulated gradients to zero
reset_gradients = [gradient.assign(tf.zeros_like(gradient)) for gradient in
                   accumulated_gradients]

# compute the gradients
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, trainable_variables)

# Note: Gradients is a list of tuples containing the gradient and the
# corresponding variable so gradient[0] is the actual gradient. Also divide
# the gradients by BATCHES_PER_STEP so the learning rate still refers to
# steps not batches.

# define operation to evaluate a batch and accumulate the gradients
evaluate_batch = [
    accumulated_gradient.assign_add(gradient[0]/BATCHES_PER_STEP)
    for accumulated_gradient, gradient in zip(accumulated_gradients,
                                              gradients)]

# define operation to apply the gradients
apply_gradients = optimizer.apply_gradients([
    (accumulated_gradient, gradient[1]) for accumulated_gradient, gradient
    in zip(accumulated_gradients, gradients)])

# define variable and operations to track the average batch loss
average_loss = tf.Variable(0., trainable=False)
update_loss = average_loss.assign_add(loss/BATCHES_PER_STEP)
reset_loss = average_loss.assign(0.)
[...]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = tf.Session(config=CONFIG)
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    data = [batch_data[i] for i in range(BATCHES_PER_STEP)]
    for batch_data in data:
        session.run([evaluate_batch, update_loss],
                    feed_dict={input: batch_data})

    # apply accumulated gradients
    session.run(apply_gradients)

    # get loss
    loss = session.run(average_loss)

    # reset variables for next step
    session.run([reset_gradients, reset_loss])
```

This should be runnable if you fill in the gaps. However I might have made a mistake while stripping it down and pasting it here. For a runnable example you can take a look into a [project](https://github.com/AlexHarn/tf-ice-model-optimization/blob/master/main.py) I am currently working on myself.

I also want to make clear that this is not the same as evaluating the loss for all the batch data at once, since you average over the gradients. This is especially important when your loss does not work well with low statistics. Take a chi square of histograms for example, calculating the average gradients for a chi square of histograms with low bin counts won't be as good as calculating the gradient on just one histogram with all the bins filled up at once.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I would like to evaluate the loss, and the gradients, for the whole (larger) batch. So, this doesn't actually simulate the synchronous SGD, as I understand it. I have > 200 classes, so I guess smaller mini-batches (like 16, or 32 samples) are significantly non-i.i.d. That is one of the reasons I would like to use larger batch size.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I think that is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to give the gradients as the values that get passed to `apply_gradients`. It can be placeholders, but it is probably easier to use the usual `compute_gradients`/`apply_gradients` combination:

```py
# Some loss measure
loss = ...
optimizer = ...
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
# gradients is a list of pairs
_, gradient_tensors = zip(*gradients)
# Apply gradients as usual
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)

# On training
# Compute some gradients
gradient_values = session.run(gradient_tensors, feed_dict={...})
# gradient_values is a sequence of numpy arrays with gradients

# After averaging multiple evaluations of gradient_values apply them
session.run(train_op, feed_dict=dict(zip(gradient_tensors, gradient_values_average)))
```

If you want to compute the averages of the gradients within TensorFlow too, that requires a bit of extra code specifically for that, maybe something like this:

```py
# Some loss measure
loss = ...
optimizer = ...
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
# gradients is a list of pairs
_, gradient_tensors = zip(*gradients)
# Apply gradients as usual
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)

# Additional operations for gradient averaging
gradient_placeholders = [tf.placeholder(t.dtype, (None,) + t.shape)
                         for t in gradient_tensors]
gradient_averages = [tf.reduce_mean(p, axis=0) for p in gradient_placeholders]

# On training
gradient_values = None
# Compute some gradients
for ...:  # Repeat for each small batch
    gradient_values_current = session.run(gradient_tensors, feed_dict={...})
    if gradient_values is None:
        gradient_values = [[g] for g in gradient_values_current]
    else:
        for g_list, g in zip(gradient_values, gradient_values_current):
            g_list.append(g)
# Stack gradients
gradient_values = [np.stack(g_list) for g_list in gradient_values)
# Compute averages
gradient_values_average = session.run(
    gradient_averages, feed_dict=dict(zip(gradient_placeholders, gradient_values)))

# After averaging multiple gradients apply them
session.run(train_op, feed_dict=dict(zip(gradient_tensors, gradient_values_average)))
```